# Including fully functional .tex documents

Tags: include, import

I'm trying to combine four separate `.tex` documents into one big "book" with each document as a chapter. I use the `import` package.

This is essentially what my main document looks like:

```
\documentclass{paper}
\usepackage{import}

\begin{document}

\section{Chapter 1}
\import{Chapters/}{Chapter1}


\section{Chapter 2}
\import{Chapters/}{Chapter2}


\section{Chapter 3}
\import{Chapters/}{Chapter3}


\section{Chapter 4}
\import{Chapters/}{Chapter4}

\end{document}
```

When I do it this way, I have to remove all options and preambles of the individual imported files, which means I can't typeset them on their own.

Chapter 1 just contains text, no preamble or options:

```
This is chapter one, with all its glorious information.
```

What I'd like:

```
\documentclass{paper}
\usepackage{xcolor, graphicx}

\graphicspath{{tex/img/}}

\setlenght\parindent{0pt}

\title{Chapter 1}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

This is chapter one, with all its glorious information.

\end{document}
```

I want to be able to look into every document, typeset them and use them individually, but also in combination within the main document. Is it possible to include/input/import `.tex`-documents without removing all of the preamble of said documents? Or is there another way to do all of this?

Comment: You may want to look into the use of `\includeonly` to make the individual chapters.

Comment: I tend to use the `docmute` package. It redefines `\input` and thus `\include` such that anything outside the `document` env is ignored. I've made proceedings like this. You just have to make sure that the packages needed by the various contributions are also in the master.

Comment: The `combine` package may help: http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/combine/combine.pdf

Comment: @daleif That was just the kind of thing I was looking for, thanks! :)